# Open Tracing: Link multiple TraceIds together into a single trace

Tags: java, opentracing

Is there any way to join multiple traces with different trace ids into a single trace? In my case I have something like the following which I would like to join together into a single trace.

```
|--- UI Trace ---------------------------------|
    |- UI Span -|
                 |-- Backend Trace -----------|
                   |- Backend Span --| |--|
```

Yes, I could refactor so that my `Backend Trace` is span within the `UI Trace`. But I'm working with some existing code where the the backend services already have an ID per request passed around via http headers. I would like to re-use the existing Backend ID instead of adding a new trace ID header to all existing requests.

Answer (score 1):

In general, 'joining traces' in the way you're describing would be part of your trace analyzer (Jaeger, LightStep, etc.) and I don't believe any of them allow for this sort of query. `TraceID` is simply a way for the analyzer to associate disparate spans into a single, logical trace.

Some options to address this would be the following -

1. Generate a trace id of the proper format on the frontend and use that as the OpenTracing `SpanContext` trace id, assuming your backend will propagate this as well if it's given to it.
2. Create a proxy that temporarily stores the spans from your UI, waits for a backend trace id to be available, and then rewrites the `SpanContext` with the trace id generated by the backend. You don't necessarily have to pass unfinished or malformed spans down - you could simply send the required pieces of data down the wire to your backend and create new spans for the UI at that point.

Comment: Generating our ID on the UI side is not possible. But, it does look like LightStep has something to solve specifically this problem of integrating with old systems: https://docs.lightstep.com/docs/opentracing-instrumentation#section-join-spans-together-to-see-the-full-picture-of-your-high-priority-operation-